# Taking a list from yaml and parsing it in jinja2 and outputting it into yaml

Tags: string, list, yaml, jinja2

Spent like 4 hours hunting through here trying to find something relevant. I know the fix here will be some sort of replacement for "| list | join ('\',\'') ", but for the life of me cannot find a similar man page. Even a pointer to a better man page would be greatly appreciated.
My desired output is:
 vlans: ["1", "3", "5", "7", "9", "17"]

I have large YAML file which contains attributes/variables for a location worth list of hosts. I am first attempting to split this file into many files that are host specific using JINJA2. When run for the vlans variable I am getting:
      vlans: "1','3','5','7','9','17"
So the entire vlans variable is treated as a single string rather than a list of strings. If I remove "| list | join ('\',\'') " from the JINJA2 code then I get this output in my destination YAML file: 
      vlans: "[u'1', u'3', u'5', u'7', u'9', u'17']"

I've tried a number of variations on the join statement and cannot seem to hit the right target. Your help is greatly appreciated.

The structure is like this:

```html
mg_uplinks:

  - { left_border_node: somehostname, left_border_intf: someinterface, 
      right_border_node: somehostname, right_border_intf: someinterface, 
      border_ae_intf: someinterface, border_esi: "some value", border_lacp_sys_id: "some value",
      mg_node: somehostname, left_mg_intf: someinterface, right_mg_intf: someinterface, mg_ae_intf: someinterface,
      link_speed: 10g,
      vlans: ["1", "3", "5", "7", "9", "17"]
      
  - { left_border_node: someotherhostname, left_border_intf: someinterface, 
      right_border_node: someotherhostname, right_border_intf: someinterface, 
      border_ae_intf: someinterface, border_esi: "some value", border_lacp_sys_id: "some value",
      mg_node: someotherhostname, left_mg_intf: someinterface, right_mg_intf: someinterface, mg_ae_intf: someinterface,
      link_speed: 10g,
      vlans: [all]      }
```

I am then parsing this info with this jinja2 code.

```html
mg_uplinks:
{% for link in mg_uplinks %}
{% if inventory_hostname == link['left_border_node'] %}
  - { local_phys_intf: "{{ link['left_border_intf'] }}", 
      border_ae_intf: "{{ link['border_ae_intf'] }}", 
      border_esi: "{{ link['border_esi'] }}", 
      border_lacp_sys_id: "{{ link['border_lacp_sys_id'] }}", 
      mg_node: "{{ link['mg_node'] }}", 
      remote_phys_intf: "{{ link['left_mg_intf'] }}", 
      remote_ae_intf: "{{ link['mg_ae_intf'] }}", 
      link_speed: "{{ link['link_speed'] }}",
      vlans: "{{ link['vlans'] | list | join ('\',\'') }}"  }

{% endif %}
{% if inventory_hostname == link['right_border_node'] %}
  - { local_phys_intf: "{{ link['right_border_intf'] }}",
      border_ae_intf: "{{ link['border_ae_intf'] }}",
      border_esi: "{{ link['border_esi'] }}",
      border_lacp_sys_id: "{{ link['border_lacp_sys_id'] }}",
      mg_node: "{{ link['mg_node'] }}",
      remote_phys_intf: "{{ link['right_mg_intf'] }}",
      remote_ae_intf: "{{ link['mg_ae_intf'] }}",
      link_speed: "{{ link['link_speed'] }}", 
      vlans: "{{ link['vlans'] | list | join ('\',\'') }}"  }

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it and thought I'd post the answer. The [' '] are not needed, and the filter I wanted was | to_yaml.

```
  intf_vlans: {{ intf.intf_vlans | to_yaml }},
```